# Error when trying to add clearDB MySQL to Heroku project

Tags: mysql, heroku

I am using Heroku and I want to add clearDB MySQL to my Heroku project in order to create a mySQL database. I want to have it on Heroku so as to give access to it to other people. However, after I have inserted my billing details, I tried to add clearDB but I get the following error:

```
Item could not be created:
An error was encountered when contacting the add-on partner to create cleardb:ignite. Please try again later.
```

So now I cannot create a simple mySQL database on Heroku because of this.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Pleas add logs from heroku-cli:
DEBUG=* heroku addons:create [add-on] --app [your-app] --wait